# Understanding AdMob Mediation Report

Tags: admob, report, mobile-ad-mediation

I need some help understanding AdMob Mediation Report, specifically the meaning of terms **Custom Events** and **Request**

**Question 1:** What exactly is a Custom Event, and how is it defined?

**Question 2:** What is considered a Request?

**Question 3:** How is Total Requests different from Unique Requests?

**Question 4:** In the screenshot below, AdMob Network had **457,292** requests. And Custom Events show **441,414** Requests. So about half went to the Mediated Network, but only **2,762** of them resulted in impressions.

Does that mean that almost half of my requests are getting wasted because the mediated network can't fill them ? Or does it mean that requests are sent to both networks at once together resulting in only 1 impression thus explaining the difference between Total Requests & Unique Requests?

Thanks in advance!

[image]